# How to automatically scale `Show` with two subplots?

Tags: plotting

### Background

I have two plot, i.e. `angle2Plot` and `speedPlot`, to be combined in `Show`. Their axises range differ a lot.

### Problem

When I combine the two plots, I found that different order of subplots in `Show` behaves differently. For example,

```
Show[speedPlot, angle2Plot]
```

,gives out bellowed picture:

[image: Show[speedPlot,angle2Plot]]

While,

```
Show[angle2Plot, speedPlot]
```

, gives out:

[image: Show[angle2Plot,speedPlot]]

### Question

It seems that the subplot firstly appeared in `Show` determines the size of `Show`. As a result, if the subplot followed is larger than the first one, it won't show all its range.

I wonder how to extend the output of `Show[angle2Plot, speedPlot]` to present all its range (just like the first picture).

Thanks. 囧rz...

Comment: Show does take the option PlotRange. Did you try that ?

Comment: @Lotus Oh, I just tried the `PlotRange` option, it do work! Another question, why I couldn't find any option within the manual of `Show` ?

Comment: It is given under Possible Issues section of the Show Documentation page. It should have been under Options.

Comment: `why I couldn't find any option within the manual of Show` it says `Show allows any option that can be applied to graphics to be given` and under graphics, you'll see the `PlotRange` there.

Comment: @Nasser  , It seems Wolfram Manual is kind of special, and a bit different from other programming language in Manual Organizing.

Comment: Most of Graphics stuff is build of top of each others. Plot for example, has its own options, but it is also a _child_ of Graphics in some OO sense, so in  `Plot` help, you'll also see this `Plot has the same options as Graphics, with the following additions and changes:` Inside `LogLogPlot` you'll also see the same things, and so on. This is very common. It is like sub-classing in OO in some sense. No need to duplicate the same help pages everywhere for common options that are in the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Nasser and @Lotus, you can resolve this issue with the use of `PlotRange`.

Which in my understanding can be done in two different ways,

First, you can utilize this option inside each `Plot` calling,

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All],Plot[x - 1, {x, -50, 10}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Secondly, you can call `PlotRange` once inside `Show`,

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}], Plot[x - 1, {x, -50, 10}], PlotRange -> All]
```

BTW, you can manually set the `PlotRange` inside each `Plot` or `Show`,

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}], Plot[x - 1, {x, -50, 10}],
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-20, 20}}]
```

[image]

Comment: The last method to customize PlotRange for each subplot is strange. seems Wolfram Language don't have a systematic **language syntax** to define its command usage.

Comment: @PureLine In what sense it is strange?